# Creating a `Labeled` with left-justification?

Tags: graphics

What is the easiest way to have a label below a plot that's left justified?

I've tried `Labeled`, but can't find a way to get the result to be left-justified on the bottom, it's displayed as centered:

```
SF = StringForm;
m = 4;
mats = RandomInteger[5, {m, 2, 2}];
label[k_] := SF["w=``", MatrixForm /@ mats[[;; k]]];
plot[k_] := Labeled[Plot[x + 1, {x, 0, 1}], label[k], Bottom];
ListAnimate[plot /@ Range[m]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use double curly brackets: `{{Bottom, Left}}`

```
SF = StringForm;
m = 4;
mats = RandomInteger[5, {m, 2, 2}];

label[k_] := SF["w=``", MatrixForm /@ mats[[;; k]]]

plot[k_] := 
  Labeled[Plot[x + 1, {x, 0, 1}], label[k], {{Bottom, Left}}

plot[2]
```

[image]